# How to display a link when there are no rows in Ag-grid table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am using AG Grid to display a table. When there are no rows, AG Grid displays a default text. What I am trying to do is, instead of text, display a link. By clicking the link, I want to open a form.
To accomplish this, I am using [noRowsOverlayComponent](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-overlay/#simple-no-rows-overlay-component). But AGGrid is not rendering the link. Here is the custom overlay component I wrote

```
import React from 'react';

export type NoRowsLinkProps = {
  text?: string;
  actionFunction?: any;
};
function NoRowsLink(props: NoRowsLinkProps) {
  debugger;
  function dummy() {}
  return (
    <div>
      <a onClick={props.actionFunction ? props.actionFunction : dummy} style={}>
        {props.text ? props.text : 'No rows to show'}
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NoRowsLink;
```

And I am passing this component to Ag-grid component using noRowsOverlayComponent prop
like below

```
<AgGridReact
.
 .
 .
 noRowsOverlayComponent={NoRowsLink}
 noRowsOverlayComponentParams={applicableNoRowsOverlayComponentParams}
 .
 .
 ./>
```

But the Ag grid is not rendering the anchor tag. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is likely related to how you're passing the custom component to the noRowsOverlayComponent prop in the Ag Grid configuration. Instead of directly passing the component class, you should pass a function that returns the component.

Here's how you can modify your code to make it work:

```
<AgGridReact
  // Other Ag Grid configurations
  noRowsOverlayComponent={() => <NoRowsLink />}
  noRowsOverlayComponentParams={applicableNoRowsOverlayComponentParams}
/>
```

By wrapping the NoRowsLink component inside an arrow function, you ensure that it is lazily instantiated and rendered as a component when needed by Ag Grid. This way, Ag Grid will correctly render your custom component as the no rows overlay.

Additionally, make sure that applicableNoRowsOverlayComponentParams is an object containing any necessary parameters for the NoRowsLink component, and pass it as the noRowsOverlayComponentParams prop.

With these changes, Ag Grid should render your custom link component as the no rows overlay, and clicking on the link should trigger the provided action function.

Comment: Sorry your solution didn't work. Would be great if you can provide a working fiddle which displays a link when there are no rows

Comment: Yeah, I mean it would be nice if I spent the time to learn about Ag.....alright fine :P here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-frog-z5gsfn

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since you posted 7 answers today, most or all of which appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Answer (score 0):

React is not rendering  element without `href` attribute.
Just place some empty href attribute.
But be aware that your click handler should prevent default, otherwise, it will refresh the page.